Use PdfEmbeddingFonts in Fast Report
I use a code example to create a report with FastReport in my Blazor app. Everything works fine but when I export the report to PDF the fonts I use are not there. How do I embed Fonts in my code?
This is the code I use.
 FastReport.Utils.Config.WebMode = true;
 Report rep = new Report();
 string path = Path.Combine("Reports", reportLayoutName);
 rep.Load(path);
 
 rep.SetParameterValue("Etichetta", model.Etichetta);
 rep.SetParameterValue("Company", model.Company);
 rep.SetParameterValue("Pratica", model.Pratica);

 rep.RegisterData(model.Fatture, "dataModel");
 
 if (rep.Report.Prepare())
 {
    PDFSimpleExport pdfExport = new PDFSimpleExport();
    pdfExport.ShowProgress = false;
    pdfExport.Subject = "";
    pdfExport.Title = "";
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    rep.Report.Export(pdfExport, ms);
    rep.Dispose();
    ms.Position = 0;
    return File(ms, "application/pdf", reportName);
  }


I can't figure out how to add fonts to the PDF.
Thank you
